# remove word from string with spaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

- I want to remove word from string including *white* spaces.
- For example if the string is `'dog cat cow'` and you remove `'dog'` it
  will return `'cat cow'`.
- If you want to remove `'cat'` it would return `'dog cow'`. It need to be
  removed white spaces before or/and after word also.

Comment: SO is not your free [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) service

Comment: it is not a homework at all, just wanted to show simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a particular word from a string along with whitespaces you can use this following function

```
function removeWord(sentence, word){
    sentence=sentence.split(" ").filter((item)=>{return item!=word}).join().replace(","," ");
    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: it writes ',' if there is two spaces after/before substring

Comment: You are removing one word at a time. So there will be no scenario for the two spaces. You can run the function and check.

Comment: I need to make sure when those cases occur too, the solution is sentence=sentence.split(" ").filter((item)=>{return item!=word}).join(' '); thanks for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done like this:

```
var str = "dog cat cow";
var word = 'cat';

console.log(replace(str, word));

function replace(str, word){
  str = str.replace(word, ""); // removing chosen word
  str = str.replace(/\s/g,''); //  removing whitespace
  return str;

}
```

Not the smallest solution but simplest imo.